# Framework tags synonym for language tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Wondering if it makes sense to others to attach the language of a given framework when the framework is used as a tag, for instance, jquery, you can't have jquery that doesn't involve javascript.

Might not be true to the definition of a "synonym", but wouldn't it make sense that questions  tagged jquery, would also benifit from a javascript tag?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest tagging as both (meaning they are not synonyms).  Removing the framework tag doesn't help much if the question is specific to the framework (eg: *How do I use the `.flop()` method on foo*).  Adding the language tag does help open the question up to more people, so I would suggest doing that (and that's indeed what I've been doing)...